# Inject EF DatabaseContext into custom ScopedService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

it seems to me that performance of injected EF inside scoped service is really low.

There is a high chance that I am using EF incorrectly in this case, but I have not been able to find proper description/documentation how to use EF in this case (Inject it into custom hosted service).

In EasyRabbit/startup.cs (ConfigureServices) are registered following services:

```
// db
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost; Database=RabbitTest; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; User ID=sa; Password=Admin1234");
});

// default REST Api
services.AddMvc();
// Configuration for Rabbit connector
services.Configure<RabbitConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("RabbitConfig"));
// Rabbit Connector
services.AddSingleton<RabbitConnector>();
// Subscriber which listens if some new message arrives
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, GenericHostedSubscriber<CalculatorInputs>>();

// Every arival message is then processed in following scope
// ApplicationDbContext dbContext is injected into this RabbitSubscribers.Adder
services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService<CalculatorInputs>, RabbitSubscribers.Adder>();
```

Now if I understand it correctly, it should automatically create db context scope for every new RabbitSubscribers.Adder scope.

Problem is that like this it can consume/process only about 50 messages per second on average.

When I comment all operations with db (AddAsync and SaveChangesAsync) from following code, then it can process about 2000 messages per second which is nice but without db useless for me :(

```
namespace EasyRabbit.RabbitSubscribers
{
    public class Adder : IScopedProcessingService<CalculatorInputs>
    {
        private ILogger<Adder> _logger;
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public Adder(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, ILogger<Adder> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _db = dbContext;

        }

        public async Task HandleMessageAsync(CalculatorInputs message)
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"Calculator: [{message.FirstNumber}] + [{message.SecondNumber}] = {message.FirstNumber + message.SecondNumber}");
            await _db.Calculations.AddAsync(new Calculation()
            {
                FirstNumber = message.FirstNumber,
                SecondNumber = message.SecondNumber,
                Result = message.FirstNumber + message.SecondNumber
            });

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to replace EF with System.Data.SqlClient (following piece of code directly used in Adder.cs), then it could process 1100 messages per second on average. But to work with DB like this is really unconvinient :-/

```
public static class DB
{
    private static string _connectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=RabbitTest; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; User ID=sa; Password=Admin1234";


    public static void AddRecord(MyDBObject myDBObject)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into test (FirstNumber, SecondNumber, Result) values (@FirstNumber, @SecondNumber, @Result)", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstNumber", myDBObject.FirstNumber);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondNumber", myDBObject.SecondNumber);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Result", myDBObject.Result);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}

public class MyDBObject
{
    public int FirstNumber { get; set; }
    public int SecondNumber { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
}
```

Whole code can be found on https://github.com/suchoss/uServiceChasis

Thanks.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Clone current repository from: https://github.com/suchoss/uServiceChasis
2. Install RabbitMQ from: https://www.rabbitmq.com/#getstarted
3. Install MSSQL
4. Change connector to DB in EasyRabbit/startup.cs (line 31)
5. Go to folder RandomNumberPairGenerator and run command dotnet run for a few seconds, then you can cancel it with ctrl+c (it creates some messages into RabbitMQ queue)
6. Run EasyRabbit project and watch how many messages per second is being processed
   *.  If you have RabbitMQ management installed you can watch performance on http://localhost:15672 (default login: guest; password: guest)

---

Edited:

Here are current measured performances:

1. EF async inside adder.cs - 230/s
2. EF without async inside adder.cs - 100/s
3. ADO.NET async - 1300/s
4. ADO.NET without async - 150/s
5. EF injected context async - 40/s
6. EF injected context without async - 65/s

scenarios 1.,2.,3.,4. have adder.cs as a singleton

scenarios 5.,6. they have adder.cs as a scoped service

Comment: Well, ORMs will always be slower. In this case, you are simply inserting a record. By creating an object and adding it to the context, you are incurring a lot of overhead. What I would suggest instead is that you create a stored procedure for inserting and import it into your context as a function. I suspect that will speed things up significantly.

Comment: Another option would be to collect batches and bulk-save every so often in order to minimize the number of calls to the DB.

Comment: Well I didn't expect it to be that slow (22x slower than direct sql insert). Few minutes ago I tried to change the code in a way that instead of injecting db context, I am using EF context directly in HandleMessageAsync method and performance increased to 230 messages/s on average. Still 5x slower than direct insert, but about 5x faster than injected EF

Comment: Well, you are also incurring overhead with the injection process. It looks like `Adder` could be a singleton.

Comment: Given your current design, I would recommend this: Make `Adder` a singleton (if possible) and keep adding to the context on `HandleMessageAsync` but don't call `SaveChangesAsync` until you have gathered, say, 100 `Calculation` objects. Otherwise, go with the imported function.

Comment: Yes, in the code on github - there is overhead with scoping - I am aware of that, but it had to be created so I was able to use (inject) db context. You are not allowed to inject dbcontext which is scoped inside a singleton. 
In my second try (few minutes ago) I already used it as a singleton so 230 messages/s is a result of having singleton with EF directly in adder. (230 messages/s is on the edge of what I need at least, but still I would like to know, why is injected db context that slow. What am I doing wrong?)

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. It's the price you pay for using an ORM and an injection scheme.

Comment: ORMs are not known for being great at database intensive operations. For situations like that, it's generally advisable to go with lightweight code and do bulk inserts.

Comment: @"don't call SaveChangesAsync until you have gathered, say, 100 Calculation objects." 
I am going to use it as a microservice, so bulk inserting is not a possibility here. But I understand. Thanks